# Scrollspy not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Since I coded the portfolio page with Bootstrap 4, I followed the documentation on Scrollspy in its latest alpha version. But it still doesn't work.

What I want to achieve:

- Much like the example in the documentation, as I scroll the page, to have the items changes its color as I scroll down, according to section I am in. Also, the navbar should remain fixed-top as it is.

[This is a working example in Bootstrap 4](https://www.codeply.com/go/7CDRomtM0D) and it seemingly looks like my code, but I can't get around my head why it doesn't work in mine.

My navbar code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand navfont" href="/">portfolio.</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> about</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> portfolio</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> contact</a>
    </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

I tried:

- Deleting the a stylings in CSS
- adding the class "active" and styling it
- adding a:focus in CSS

Check the whole thing on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pablovester/pen/ZKJxLL).

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've missed 2 small things, first thing the nav need the id of `navbar1`, this is from the body `data-target="#navbar1"` so the nav would become:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top" style="background-color: #fc7a57;" id="navbar1">
```

After that this will add a class on `a.nav-link` called `active`, on so you will need a class like

```
.active { color:#fff }
```

Here a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jbatley/pen/WjPxXY) of my working copy of your code

Comment: It worked like a charm and I didn't have to write a single line of JS! thank you, Josh. Incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar. [You can can look at this fork of your code to see the JS](http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/LyqZWZ).

All in your HTML was I added `class="section"` to tell the jQuery when to add those active classes. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Indeed it worked! I even thought the JS library URL was wrong. Thank you! But can I have jQuery to target ids too, right?

Comment: You can, however the only thing is, you'd have to adjust it to know when it went over that ID. I find it much easier to just set a class to it.